# SQL Server: "Could not find the Database Engine startup handle"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

When trying to install SQL Server Express 2016 from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) for database related software projects, I get the error message as the loading bar finishes, stating:

> "Could not find the Database Engine startup handle".

I've looked and tried solutions from other questions similar to this, but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered my question below as I found the answer out eventually and I feel people might be going through the same struggle! :)

The installation failed for me due to using the standard/default settings during installation. When doing this, the SQL Windows service will run under the NT Service\MSSQL$V2016 account.

**After changing this login to a valid login (an existing local user), the server started correctly, and SQL Server Express 2016 installed and worked as it should.**.

Comment: Just FYI MS recommends using the minimum amount of permissions needed for the service user. Admin privs may not be necessary. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions Also, just FYI don't use a regular user login, when those get disabled so does your SQL server. :)

Comment: https://www.zubairalexander.com/blog/could-not-find-the-database-engine-startup-handle-in-sql-server-2016/