# Can't connect to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, authentication

I installed SQL Server 2012 sometime ago and forgot the administrator password I set during setup.

Actually, I can't connect at all because SQL Server isn't even running.

The Event Viewer has the following message:

> Error 5(Access is denied.) occurred while opening file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.PACHYDERM\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf' to obtain configuration information at startup. An invalid startup option might have caused the error. Verify your startup options, and correct or remove them if necessary.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall it, but I get the exact same circumstances (can't login/can't start).  Whatever was there, is of no use since I can't get to it.  I want to start fresh, but I don't know what to do next, what to look for, or where to look for it.  I basically just want a fresh SQL playground to try to teach myself SSIS.

I know people here like to sneer at these kinds of questions and point out how they've been asked before. Great! Point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Uninstall, then completely delete `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\`, then reinstall.  See if that works.

Comment: Which user is the SQL Server service running under, and which user owns and has rights on that file

Comment: it looks like the "Administrators" account owns the file

Comment: @squilman, I'll try renaming that folder and re-installing; thanks

Comment: I didn't (maybe that was a mistake).
But this time, I got this error during install that didn't occur the last time:
```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2012  Setup
------------------------------
The following error has occurred:
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
[etc]```

Comment: after uninstalling everything with 2012 in it, I re-installed and now I get this error: "Could not find the Database Engine startup handle." Not ever sure what this means.

Comment: this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398787/sql-server-could-not-find-the-database-engine-startup-handle) says use a not-the-default log in, i.e., a local user; when I try this, I still can't even start the service

Comment: the event viewer says this: "SQL Server could not spawn FRunCommunicationsManager thread. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about possible related problems."; what does this mean?

Comment: I'm using the "Local System" built-in account for the "Log on as" setting; I tried adding "-mSQLCMD" as a startup parameter, but now I can't remember why I needed to do that

Comment: when trying to start the service and failing, I'm getting this in the event log:  "FCB::Open failed: Could not open file e:\sql11_main_t.obj.x86release\sql\mkmastr\databases\objfre\i386\model.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 21(The device is not ready.)."  does this help anyone understand what's happening? (also for MSDBData.mdf, but not master or any ldf files)

Comment: I found this statement: "NET START MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS /f /T3608" and ran it (with my instance name) and the service finally started, but I still can't run sqlcmd from the cmd prompt: "Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. ."

Comment: enabled nameed pipes, and tcp/ip; fixed the mdf and ldf file paths with SQLCMD; but I still can't login; the SQLCMD commands to add/fix the sa login aren't allowing me to connect through SSMS with SQL authentication

Comment: when I try to use windows auth, it says "Login failed for user 'MicrosoftAccount\mystuffhere@hotmail.com'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)"